# Creating embedded documents, doesn't seem to create relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have the following models defined in Rails, with Mongoid:

```
Class Character
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :n, as: name, type: String
  field :p, as: :positions, type: Array
  field :o, as: :roles, type: Array 
  field :r, as: :resource, type: String
  embeds_one :base_stat
end

class BaseStat
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :character
end
```

I'm trying to seed my database with documents that have these relationships 1) because I'd have to eventually and 2) so I can test I'm using Mongoid correctly. I've tried a couple of different ways to seed it, but every single time, I can create Character documents, then create BaseStat documents based off a Character document, but calling character.base_stat returns nil.

Here are the things I've tried in db/seeds.rb that didn't throw errors:

```
ch = Character.create!([etc])
ch.build_base_stat([etc])

Character.create!(name: value, name: value, base_stat: BaseStat.new(name: value, name:value))

ch = Character.create!([etc])
ch.create_base_stat([etc])
```

I've also tried using ch.base_stat.create! (which threw an error when I called rake db:setup).

I know that both the Character and BaseStat documents are created because I can search in the Rails console for the Character documents that were seeded (a = Character.where(name: value)[0] and b = BaseStat.where(name:value)[0]). But it looks like the relationship isn't being stored.

Calling a.metadata also throws a NoMethodError.

I don't have any controllers set up, just the models and the entries in db/seeds.rb. I feel like I must be missing something fundamental because, well, I've been hunting through StackOverflow and haven't seen anything that fixed this.

Versions:
Mongoid 4.0.0.alpha2
Rails 4.0.1

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a very basic test? Can you open the rails console create a Character, save it, then add a BaseStat to it and save that?

```
c = Character.new
b = BaseStat.new
b.name = "test"
c.base_stat = b
c.save
c
```

Does that print out your new record with the BaseStat embedded? If it does then there must be something wrong with the syntax or method in the seeds.

Comment: Weird! It does. I currently only have one seed. Would you mind taking a look at it? 
`Character.create!(n: "Aatrox", p: ["top", "jungle"], o: ["offtank", "glass cannon"], r: "health",
  stats: BaseStat.new(hp: 395, hp18: 1925, hpr: 5.75, hpr18: 14.75, ad: 55, ad18: 112.6, as: 0.651, as18: 0.983, ar: 14, ar18: 82.4, mr: 30, mr18: 52.5, ms: 345, r: 150))`

(I changed Character model so it's embeds_one :stats, class_name "BaseStat." BaseStat model is still embedded_in :character)

Comment: Assuming you have all of those fields added to the BaseStat model it seems correct to me. After running this seed you should be able to find that BaseStat by doing Character.first.stats, does that work? I don't think any relationship data needs to be stored for embedded documents. Its more like a pseudo association.

Comment: No, calling Character.first.stats returns nil. It's odd. (Character.first does return the right result though.)

Answer (score 0):

Quoting Mongoid docs, this could be why:

> One core difference between Mongoid and Active Record from a behavior standpoint is that Mongoid does not automatically save child relations for relational associations. This is for performance reasons.

Try adding `autosave: true` to your `base_stat` relation:

```
embeds_one :base_stat, autosave: true
```